# About Ubuntu Support

Tags: canonical, support

I want to ask about the Pricing Model for Ubuntu Support for Server Deployments [from canonical](http://www.canonical.com/services) on the order of 30 instances (12.04 and 14.04 LTS)

What is the pricing and  support framework that Canonical Provides?

What instance management services can they provide?

Comment: I didn't understand your Question but keep in Mind Ubuntu is FREE and Open Source.

Comment: @Yousef's while ubuntu is Open Source, Canonical offers [support services](http://www.canonical.com/services) for enterprises and institutions to manage/deploy/service ubuntu systems

Answer (score 1):

This site is primarily for technical support questions and answers from the community.

This webpage has information about Ubuntu Advantage support from Canonical; it is advisable you speak with a Canonical Sales rep directly, rather than ask for pricing from a community of volunteers and enthusiasts.

http://www.ubuntu.com/server/management